# pass const pointer of large struct to a function or a go channel

Tags: go

How to pass const pointer of large struct to a function or a go channel. 
Purpose of this ask is:

1. Avoid the accidental modification of pointer by the function
2. Avoid the copy of the struct object while passing to
   function/channel

This functionality is very common in C++, C#, Java, but how can we achieve the same in golang?

**============== Update 2 ===================**

Thank you @zarkams, @mkopriva and @peterSO
It was the compiler optimization causing the same result in both byValue() and byPointer().
Modified the functions byValue() and byPointer() by adding 
**data.array[0] = reverse(data.array[0])**, just to make compiler not to make the functions inline.

```
func byValue(data Data) int {
    data.array[0] = reverse(data.array[0])
    return len(data.array)
}

func byPointer(data *Data) int {
    data.array[0] = reverse(data.array[0])
    return len(data.array)
}

func reverse(s string) string {
    runes := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(runes)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        runes[i], runes[j] = runes[j], runes[i]
    }
    return string(runes)
}
```

After that running the benchmarks, passing by pointer was much efficient than passing by value.

```
C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>go test -bench=.
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkByValue-4         18978             58228 ns/op               3 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkByPointer-4    40034295                33.1 ns/op             3 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/C_/Users/anikumar/Desktop/TestGo      3.336s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>go test -gcflags -N -run=none -bench=.
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkByValue-4         20961             59380 ns/op               3 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkByPointer-4    31386213                36.5 ns/op             3 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/C_/Users/anikumar/Desktop/TestGo      3.909s
```

**============== Update ===================**

Based on feedback from @zerkms, I created a test to find the performance difference between copy by value and copy by the pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

const size = 99999

// Data ...
type Data struct {
    array [size]string
}

func main() {
    // Preparing large data
    var data Data
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        data.array[i] = "This is really long string"
    }

    // Starting test
    const max = 9999999999
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        byValue(data)
    }
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("By Value took %s", elapsed)

    start = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        byPointer(&data)
    }
    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("By Pointer took %s", elapsed)
}

func byValue(data Data) int {
    data.array[0] = reverse(data.array[0])
    return len(data.array)
}

func byPointer(data *Data) int {
    data.array[0] = reverse(data.array[0])
    return len(data.array)
}

func reverse(s string) string {
    runes := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(runes)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        runes[i], runes[j] = runes[j], runes[i]
    }
    return string(runes)
}
```

After 10 iterations of the above program, I did not find any difference in execution time.

```
C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:52:03 By Value took 5.2798936s
2020/02/16 15:52:09 By Pointer took 5.3466306s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:52:18 By Value took 5.3596692s
2020/02/16 15:52:23 By Pointer took 5.2724685s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:52:29 By Value took 5.2359938s
2020/02/16 15:52:34 By Pointer took 5.2838676s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:52:42 By Value took 5.8374936s
2020/02/16 15:52:49 By Pointer took 6.9524342s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:53:40 By Value took 5.4364867s
2020/02/16 15:53:46 By Pointer took 5.8712875s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:53:54 By Value took 5.5481591s
2020/02/16 15:54:00 By Pointer took 5.5600314s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:54:10 By Value took 5.4753771s
2020/02/16 15:54:16 By Pointer took 6.4368084s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:54:24 By Value took 5.4783356s
2020/02/16 15:54:30 By Pointer took 5.5312314s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:54:39 By Value took 5.4853542s
2020/02/16 15:54:45 By Pointer took 5.5541164s

C:\Users\anikumar\Desktop\TestGo>TestGo.exe
2020/02/16 15:54:57 By Value took 5.4633856s
2020/02/16 15:55:03 By Pointer took 5.4863226s
```

Looks like @zerkms is right. It is not because of language, it is because of modern hardware.

Comment: First rule of performance optimisation: measure and prove this optimisation makes sense.

Comment: I am sorry, I just started learning golang. But theoretically copy by value should be inefficient. I am not aware if golang does some magic to make this operation efficient.

Comment: "theoretically copy by value should be inefficient" --- or the opposite? Modern architectures are extremely efficient in copying data (this is language independent). Allocating in the heap is far from being free (this also applies to every other garbage collected language). That's why you first need to confirm what you're trying to achieve makes any sense (most likely it does not)

Comment: @Anil8753 that's not a "large struct" however. That's a small struct with one field of type slice. Slices are headers that contain a pointer to the underlying array, plus `len` and `cap`. So all you're copying is 3 integers, and not, as you seem to assume, 999999 strings.

Comment: @Anil8753 also there's no such thing as "const pointer" in Go. In the spec [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) the first section lists the types that can be used for declaring constant values, pointers are not one of them.

Comment: @Anil8753 please read this https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals to get a better sense of slices and arrays. And a simple code example to illustrate that it **is** true: https://play.golang.com/p/F9O5JtJPKIy

Comment: @Anil8753 I forgot to add the append, here's the updated version: https://play.golang.com/p/qKD43YnWqWG

Comment: @mkopriva, updated the code, results are same. Looks like copy operation is efficient

Comment: @Anil8753 keep in mind that your byValue and byPointer functions are very basic and I'm pretty sure they are optimized away. The compiler can tell that all you do is read the length of an *array* which, in Go, is a constant. Try something more complex, something the compiler won't be confident enough to elide. For example try this: https://play.golang.com/p/tqbXjvo7mCt (do you still get the same results? Because I don't)

Comment: @Anil8753 another thing to note is that Go standard library has a `testing` package which provides some useful functionality for benchmarking. For example next to your main.go file add a main_test.go file (the file name is important) and add [these two benchmarks to it](https://play.golang.com/p/ZKSe0WwVgUk) and then from inside the folder run this command `go test -run=none -bench=.`, this will print how many operations were executed, how much time a single operation took, how much memory a single operation required, and how many allocations were required.

Comment: @mkopriva: Your [two benchmarks](https://play.golang.com/p/ZKSe0WwVgUk) are microbenchmarks. See my answer.

Comment: @peterSO my benchmarks are intended to be used with the updated functions from the previous comment.

Comment: @peterSO i.e. https://play.golang.com/p/8YBW1F75Jft if I run that I get quite the different results indicating that there's a huge advantage passing around a pointer instead of a non-pointer in the case where the data pointed is big.

Comment: @peterSO also, fwiw, I do agree with the meaninglessness of microbenchmarks and that's why I did upvote your answer.

Comment: @mkopriva:  Introducing reflection, a complex, runtime feature, into this discussion is not a good idea, "Reflection is subtle even for experts." Rob Pike. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/abpF-Ykd0Z0/RUbDGKonku0J.

Comment: @peterSO sure it does introduce complexity, but so does a real world application. The reflection code in both those functions is exactly the same and therefore I doubt that the hidden complexity of reflection renders the result of the benchmark invalid. And to be clear the purpose of the benchmark is *not* to show real world numbers but to illustrate that the use of a pointer-to-a-large-object is more efficient than the use of a large-object.

Comment: @peterSO  This can of course be illustrated without reflection, if you allow me to  assume that the realworld program's use of the object is not gonna be simple enough to be optimized away then we can use the original functions and run the benchmarks with optimization turned off. https://gist.github.com/mkopriva/0a6c14c28a7d45b2e10e832efaf8b378

Comment: @peterSO as an illustrantion of the difference in efficiency between using an 8-byte object and a 799992-byte object, would this still be considered wrong?

Comment: "I created a test to find the performance difference" --- it's much more complicated than that: allocating on the heap creates an additional GC pressure that would be extremely tricky (impossible) to measure long term.

Answer (score 3):

Meaningless microbenchmarks produce meaningless results.

---

In Go, all arguments are passed by value.

---

For your updated example (TestGo),

```
$ go version
go version devel +6917529cc6 Sat Feb 15 16:40:12 2020 +0000 linux/amd64
$ go run microbench.go
2020/02/16 13:12:56 By Value took 2.877045229s
2020/02/16 13:12:59 By Pointer took 2.875847918s
$
```

Go compilers are usually optimizing compilers. For example,

```
./microbench.go:39:6: can inline byValue
./microbench.go:43:6: can inline byPointer
./microbench.go:26:10: inlining call to byValue
./microbench.go:33:12: inlining call to byPointer
```

There is no function call overhead. Therefore, there is no difference in execution time.

`microbench.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

const size = 99999

// Data ...
type Data struct {
    array [size]string
}

func main() {
    // Preparing large data
    var data Data
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        data.array[i] = "This is really long string"
    }

    // Starting test
    const max = 9999999999
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        byValue(data)
    }
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("By Value took %s", elapsed)

    start = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        byPointer(&data)
    }
    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("By Pointer took %s", elapsed)
}

func byValue(data Data) int {
    return len(data.array)
}

func byPointer(data *Data) int {
    return len(data.array)
}
```

---

---

ADDENDUM

[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246789/pass-const-pointer-of-large-struct-to-a-function-or-a-go-channel#comment106569129_60246789): @Anil8753 another thing to note is that Go standard library has a testing package which provides some useful functionality for benchmarking. For example next to your main.go file add a main_test.go file (the file name is important) and add [these two benchmarks to it](https://play.golang.com/p/ZKSe0WwVgUk) and then from inside the folder run this command go test -run=none -bench=., this will print how many operations were executed, how much time a single operation took, how much memory a single operation required, and how many allocations were required. – mkopriva

---

Go compilers are usually optimizing compilers. Modern hardware is usually heavily optimized.

For mkopriva's microbenchmark,

```
$ go test microbench.go mkopriva_test.go -bench=.
BenchmarkByValue-4     1000000000   0.289 ns/op   0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkByPointer-4   1000000000   0.575 ns/op   0 B/op   0 allocs/op
$
```

However, for mkopriva's microbenchmark with a sink,

```
$ go test microbench.go sink_test.go -bench=.
BenchmarkByValue-4     1000000000   0.576 ns/op   0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkByPointer-4   1000000000   0.592 ns/op   0 B/op   0 allocs/op
$
```

`mkopriva_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkByValue(b *testing.B) {
    var data Data
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        byValue(data)
    }
}

func BenchmarkByPointer(b *testing.B) {
    var data Data
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        byPointer(&data)
    }
}
```

`sink_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

var banchInt int

func BenchmarkByValue(b *testing.B) {
    var data Data
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        banchInt = byValue(data)
    }
}

func BenchmarkByPointer(b *testing.B) {
    var data Data
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        banchInt = byPointer(&data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you showed the real numbers of my benchmark or, if you disagree with the use of reflection-to-bypass-optimization as a tool in benchmarks, then removing the numbers might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a really good question, and I don't know why people have marked it down.  (That is, the original question of using a "const pointer" to pass a large struct.)

The simple answer is that Go has no way to indicate that a function (or channel) taking a pointer is not going to modify the thing pointed to. Basically it is up to the creator of the function to document that the function will not modify the structure.

@Anil8753 as you explicitly mention channels I should explain something further.  Typically when using a channel you are passing data to another go-routine.  If you pass a pointer to the struct then the sender must be careful not to modify the struct after it has been sent (at least while the receiver could be reading it) and vice versa.  This would create a data race.

For this reason I typically pass structs by value with channels.  If you need to create something in the sender for exclusive use of the receiver then create a struct (on the heap) and send a pointer to it in the channel and never use it again (even assigning nil to the pointer to make this explicit).

@zerkms makes a very good point that before you optimize you should understand what is happening and make measurements.  However, in this case there is an obvious performance benefit to not copying memory around.  Whether this happens when the struct is 1KB, 1MB, or 1GB there will come a point where you want to pass by "reference" (ie a pointer to the struct) rather than by value (as long as you know the struct won't be modified or don't care if it is).

In theory and in practice copy by value will become very inefficient when the struct becomes large enough or the function is called many times.

Comment: For what it's worth, even in C, `const` can be a meaningless annotation in some cases. C++'s rules work better than C's but in the end you're usually stuck with trusting someone who *says* "I won't muck with your data" to in fact actually not muck with your data. :-) Go doesn't give you a language keyword with which to make promises that you might or might not keep, but you can still make the promises, and keep them.

Comment: @torek Absolutely (and I was going to make the point that you can cast away constness). However, it does give some help to the compiler to warn you of problems of an accidental nature, and it is more explicit than some comment somewhere.